# Issue with JdbcTemplate BeanPropertyRowMapper - setting int & double field as 0 instead of actual value

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-orm

I am trying to fetch an record from a database using Spring Jdbctemplate.. In JdbcTemplate I am trying to automate data bind by making use of the class BeanPropertyRowMapper... My database table column name-type & model object field name-type are same...I implemented this API but I am not getting expected results.. For int & double fields I am getting 0 & 0.0 value even though these are different values in database...

Please help to solve this problem... My code is like below,

```
@Override
public DiscountDetail getDiscountDetailById(int ID) throws ServiceException 
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_DISCOUNT where Id="+ID;
    logger.info("sql :"+sql);
    List<DiscountDetail> discounts  = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(DiscountDetail.class));

    if (discounts.size() == 1) {
        logger.info("discount :"+discounts.get(0).toString());
        return discounts.get(0);
    }   
    return null;
}
```

DescountDetail.java

public class DiscountDetail extends GenericEntity{

```
private int discountId,higherLimit,lowerLimit;
private double discountPercentage;

public int getDiscountId() {
    return discountId;
}

public void setDiscountId(int discountId) {
    this.discountId = discountId;
}

public int getHigherLimit() {
    return higherLimit;
}

public void setHigherLimit(int higherLimit) {
    this.higherLimit = higherLimit;
}

public int getLowerLimit() {
    return lowerLimit;
}

public void setLowerLimit(int lowerLimit) {
    this.lowerLimit = lowerLimit;
}

public double getDiscountPercentage() {
    return discountPercentage;
}

public void setDiscountPercentage(double discountPercentage) {
    this.discountPercentage = discountPercentage;
}


public String toString() 
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    sb.append("discountId: " + discountId);
    sb.append(", higherLimit:" + higherLimit);
    sb.append(", lowerLimit:" + lowerLimit);
    sb.append(", discountPercentage:" + discountPercentage);
    sb.append(super.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

```
--
-- Table structure for table `TBL_DISCOUNT_DETAIL`
--

CREATE TABLE `TBL_DISCOUNT_DETAIL` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DiscountId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `HigherLimit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LowerLimit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DiscountPercentage` double NOT NULL,
  `CreatedOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `UpdatedOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdatedBy` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VersionId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Actual Output:

2018-05-08 01:28:15 INFO  InventoryDAO:1052 - sql :SELECT * FROM TBL_DISCOUNT where Id=30
2018-05-08 01:28:15 INFO  InventoryDAO:1056 - discount :**discountId: 0**, **higherLimit:0**, **lowerLimit:0**, **discountPercentage:0.0**: ID[30]: CreatedBy SYSTEM on 2018-05-07 19:06:42.0, UpdatedBy Rahul on 2018-05-07 19:06:42.0:V[2]

Expected Output:

2018-05-08 01:28:15 INFO  InventoryDAO:1052 - sql :SELECT * FROM TBL_DISCOUNT where Id=30
2018-05-08 01:28:15 INFO  InventoryDAO:1056 - discount :**discountId: 1**, **higherLimit:5**, **lowerLimit:20**, **discountPercentage:5.0**: ID[30]: CreatedBy SYSTEM on 2018-05-07 19:06:42.0, UpdatedBy Rahul on 2018-05-07 19:06:42.0:V[2]

Comment: You should probably use a prepared statement for your SQL to start off. Also, need the column names to verify that the Bean Mapper is working as intended.

Comment: @Compass....There was silly mistake from my side... I was getting wrong table name... Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that if you're using a BeanPropertyRowMapper, you're also agreeing to allow it to actually map your database field names to your object based on its internal logic.

Particularly important is [this bit from the JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html):

> Column values are mapped based on matching the column name as obtained from result set metadata to public setters for the corresponding properties. The names are matched either directly or by transforming a name separating the parts with underscores to the same name using "camel" case.

So, in this case, you're using

```
new BeanPropertyRowMapper(DiscountDetail.class)
```

and based on the DiscountDetail class, you should have also defined the column names in your target database table as:

```
discountId
higherLimit
lowerLimit
discountPercentage
```

Or as:

```
discount_id
higher_limit
lower_limit
discount_percentage
```

Most likely, the names of the public setter methods in DiscountDetail don't match the field names of the underlying table.

Comment: Yes Micgael..... I had mapped my database field names with my object.... Still I am facing this issue...

Comment: @rahulshalgar Have you tried varying the column names? `discount_id` instead of `DiscountId`, like suggested in the answer

Comment: @Micgaek Peacock....There was silly mistake from my side... I was getting wrong table name... Issue has been fixed... Thank you so much for your co-operation...

Comment: Yes - TBL_DISCOUNT_DETAIL vs TBL_DISCOUNT. It's those little details that get you

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 requirements for fields of the javabean class `DiscountDetail` to not be null:

- name matching: 1. the java class field name is the same as the db column name 2.or  column name is underscore separated, and field name is in corresponding camel case
- The field has public setter